# Sharing mutable state between clients using async (tokio) rust-websocket

Tags: asynchronous, websocket, rust, rust-tokio

I am writing a websocket server in Rust using rust-websocket and its Tokio-based async system. I can serve clients just fine, however, I can not figure out how to share mutable state between the clients. Here is some (partial) code demonstrating this issue:

```rust
let mut core = Core::new().unwrap();
let handle = core.handle();
let server = Server::bind("localhost:62831", &handle).unwrap();

let mut state = State{
    ...
};

let f = server.incoming()
    .map_err(|InvalidConnection {error, ..}| error)
    .for_each(|upgrade, _)| {
        let f = upgrade.accept()
            .and_then(|s, _| {
                let ctx = ClientContext{
                    // some other per-client values
                    state: &mut state,
                }
                ...
                return s.send(Message::binary(data).into())
                    .and_then(move |s| Ok(s, ctx)); // this could be the complete wrong way to insert context into the stream
            }).and_then(|s, ctx| {
                // client handling code here
            });

            handle.spawn(f
                .map_err(...)
                .map(...)
            );
            return Ok(())
    });

core.run(f).unwrap();
```

This code errors with this:

```
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `**state`, which is owned by the current function
   --> src/main.rs:111:27
    |
111 |                 .and_then(|(s, _)| {
    |                           ^^^^^^^^ may outlive borrowed value `**state`
...
114 |                         state: &mut state,
    |                                     ----- `**state` is borrowed here
    |
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `**state` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword, as shown:
    |                 .and_then(move |(s, _)| {
```

When trying the compiler's suggestion, I get this:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of captured outer variable in an `FnMut` closure
   --> src/main.rs:111:27
    |
111 |                 .and_then(move |(s, _)| {
    |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot move out of captured outer variable in an `FnMut` closure

error: `state` does not live long enough
   --> src/main.rs:114:37
    |
114 |                         state: &mut state,
    |                                     ^^^^^ does not live long enough
...
122 |                 })
    |                 - borrowed value only lives until here
    |
    = note: borrowed value must be valid for the static lifetime...
```

I also tried wrapping the state in a `RefCell` (creating the `RefCell` right after the state itself), however, the compiler gives a similar move error since it tries to move the `RefCell` into the closure that creates the client context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're pretty close with the [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html). What you need now is an [`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) to wrap that `RefCell` so you can clone the `Rc` and not capture the `RefCell` itself.

```
let shared_state = Rc::new(RefCell::new(State::new())));
incoming().for_each(move |s, _| {
    let shared_state = shared_state.clone();  // Left uncaptured
    shared_state.borrow_mut().do_mutable_state_stuff(); // Could panic
});
```

Note that since you're using `Rc`'s and `RefCell`'s now, you'll likely need to go ahead and convert your `ClientContext` struct to storing an Rc> instead of a `&mut State`. It may be possible to keep using `&mut State`'s for some things, but your `&mut State`'s will be tied to the lifetime of the [`RefMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefMut.html), and if you keep it alive until the next closure runs, the borrows will panic (or fail if you use the `try_` variants).

Also keep in mind if you decide you want to have multiple threads in your reactor, you will just need to change `Rc` to [`Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html), and `RefCell` to [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html), which is a very natural conversion when it's needed.